# Tor Browser 7.0.9 can't print page to file

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, ubuntu, fedora

My desktop OS is Fedora 26 and the Tor browser is 7.0.9.

I found tor browser can't print as print to file, it produces nothing. The print preview looks nice but doesn't produce any file (PDF or PS) when print as print to file.

I also tried this on Ubuntu 17.10 and also have the same problem.

Maybe this is a bug. Or can anyone workaround this problem ?

Comment: This is likely related to the patches for 7.0.9, which disables access to file:// URLs due to a potential leak.

Comment: Mmm... you could be correct. However, this cause an important feature malfunction. I guess the developers need a much elegant way to avoid file:// leak.

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 as well as 14.04. A non-ideal workaround I've used is to save the file in the `/tmp` directory then move it to your desired location from there.